# Stop audio recorder on its own after time delay in c# ( using NAudio)

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

I am making an audio recorded using NAudio in C# and i need to remove the stop button used and simply stop the recording on its own after some time delay.

The code for the record event is

```
     private void cmbRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            outputFilename = "file address";

            waveInStream = new WaveIn(44100,2);
            writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveInStream.WaveFormat);

            waveInStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveInStream_DataAvailable);
            waveInStream.StartRecording();


            // Just controling the objects on the screen.
            cmbRecord.Enabled = false;
            cmbStop.Enabled = true;

    } 


     void waveInStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        writer.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        int secondsRecorded = (int)(writer.Length / writer.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond);

    }
```

The stop button is given as

```
      private void cmbStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        waveInStream.StopRecording();
        waveInStream.Dispose();
        waveInStream = null;
        writer.Close();
        writer = null;

        cmbRecord.Enabled = true;
        cmbStop.Enabled = false;
    }
```

I need to stop the recording automatically inside the cmbRecord_Click event. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), set the `Interval` and copy the code in `cmbStop_Click` event over to timer's `OnTick` event. Enable the timer in the `mbRecord_Click` event and  & remember to disable the timer in `cmbStop_Click` event

**Edit:**

Create a new timer and set its value

//put this line in your form class level

```
  System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer=new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); //create a new Timer
```

//put these two into your form constructor just after `InitializeComponent()`;

```
mytimer.Interval=1000; //set the interval to 1 second.
mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytimer_Tick);
```

Enable the timer in the mbRecord_Click event

```
private void cmbRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            outputFilename = "file address";

            waveInStream = new WaveIn(44100,2);
            writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveInStream.WaveFormat);

            waveInStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveInStream_DataAvailable);
            waveInStream.StartRecording();


            // Just controling the objects on the screen.
            cmbRecord.Enabled = false;
            cmbStop.Enabled = true;

            //Enable the timer to fire
            mytimer.Enabled = true;

}
```

Stop recording after 1 second..

```
void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
        waveInStream.StopRecording();
        waveInStream.Dispose();
        waveInStream = null;
        writer.Close();
        writer = null;

        cmbRecord.Enabled = true;
        cmbStop.Enabled = false;
//disable the timer here so it won't fire again...
        mytimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you help me with the code, i am a total newbie to c#.

Comment: Actually while trying to create the new timer i am getting an "Invalid token '+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" error and then a "method must have a return type error." Where am i going wrong?

Comment: you need to move two line from the top to your Form's constructor, see my update

Comment: This is an old question but i want to write a comment. Just use Mark's approach because you can't save exact amount of data while using timer. I mean when i record 10 seconds, TotalTime will be 9.90 sec.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may want to bear in mind - there will be a `DataAvailable` callback *after* the call to `StopRecording` (or during, depending on the callback model used), so you might want to delay closing the WaveFileWriter until you have written everything.

Have a look at the [VoiceRecorder](https://web.archive.org/web/20180106152802/http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com:80/) sample project which uses NAudio and stops recording after 60 seconds. I explain in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100701172240/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx) how recording is automatically stopped.

```
long maxFileLength = this.recordingFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 60;

int toWrite = (int)Math.Min(maxFileLength - writer.Length, bytesRecorded);
if (toWrite > 0)
    writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRecorded);
else
    Stop();
```