# C# Play wav file with selected range time

Tags: c#, audio, wav, playback

Would you please give me solution due to  play wav file with selected range time via C# ?

I used NAudio, but it seems not support this feature.

Thanks

Comment: Thank for you reply.
I use Naudio. i want play a  audio file(wav file) with selected time .
Example: i want to play a audio file from 3 sec to 5 sec.
Do you have any suggestion  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:
[How do I create a seekbar in C#\NAudio Music Player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982914/how-do-i-create-a-seekbar-in-c-naudio-music-player)
It has `audioFileReader.SetPosition()` and `audioFileReader.Seek()` which you can use to set your range.

Comment: Hey, i need to stop at time. i want to play from 0.4 sec to 5 sec.
How i stop on time .

Comment: @Jimmy Once you have set your position (following the advice on the above link) use a timer from that position to your end point. See Bolu's andswer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203736/stop-audio-recorder-on-its-own-after-time-delay-in-c-sharp-using-naudio he explains it very well. He's also provided code.

Comment: Thank you so  much.
there is any way i create new file audio file with new length ?
Because i need small time, about millisecond , then using timer cant reach accurately. Thank

Comment: @Jimmy Just use Length() A really good example is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tumpkl-xJuA It's worth having a look at his other videos too as he knows his stuff. Also there is a link to help / example files. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jimmy Brilliant. Have a great weekend :D